# classic list mode in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server

I nostalgia to use the classic mode **new-upload-actions-settings** of SharePoint 2007/2010 list in SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, try to edit your list view and at the toolbar type select Show Toolbar

Comment: Thanks it works but not as I desired , the find search is overlapped on toolbar ? can it removed ?

Comment: you can remove `Search Box` by unchecking `display Search box` option in `Miscellaneous` section when editing your list view web part, also check the details in my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible as the following:

- Edit your Page.
- Edit your List.
- In `Toolbar Type`: Select `Show Toolbar`.

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

Based on your new requirement in comment: you can remove `Search Box` by unchecking `display Search box` option in `Miscellaneous` section  as shown below

[image]